# Why is my code repeating data scraped from the 'salary' variable?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am tryping to scrape data from indeed. Variables: `job_title` and `company` work fine, but `salary` returns the same data over and over on each line. Can anyone help fix this? Url saved within code for anyone wanting to check the HTML. Thanks!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://au.indeed.com/jobs?q=Software%20Engineer&l=Adelaide%20Region%20SA&radius=100&vjk=ca36e39d39db9210"
r = requests.get(url)

webpage = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")


job_card = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'job_seen_beacon')
for item in job_card:
  job_title = item.find('span').text.strip()

  company = item.find('span', class_ = 'companyName').text.strip()


  s = soup.find('div', class_ = 'metadata salary-snippet-container')
  for span in s:
    salary = span.find('span').text.strip()


    print(job_title, company, salary)
```

> > returns:
> > Software Engineer BOEING $85,000 - $100,000 a year
> > new Hudson Australia $85,000 - $100,000 a year
> > Software Engineer WiseTech Global $85,000 - $100,000 a year
> > Software Engineer (Integrations) Honeywell $85,000 - $100,000 a year
> > Software Support Engineer Fivecast $85,000 - $100,000 a year
> > Software Engineer (Practitioner) Rheinmetall Defence Australia Pty Ltd $85,000 - $100,000 a year
> > new Paxus Australia Pty Ltd $85,000 - $100,000 a year
> > Software Engineer Fivecast $85,000 - $100,000 a year
> > Software Engineer (PC Applications) Codan Limited $85,000 - $100,000 a year
> > Full Stack Software Engineer Honeywell $85,000 - $100,000 a year
> > Software Test Engineer Topcon Positioning Systems $85,000 - $100,000 a year
> > Software Engineer Staff - ATMS Lockheed Martin Australia $85,000 - $100,000 a year
> > new The University of Adelaide $85,000 - $100,000 a year
> > new Rapid Global $85,000 - $100,000 a year
> > new Capgemini Australia $85,000 - $100,000 a year

Comment: I believe there was a problem with `s = soup.find`, it should dive into the `item.find` instead of reloading `soup.find`

Comment: I don't see any salary mentions when I open the URL. Even your code returns `None` value for the variable `salary`.

Comment: @IshanShishodiya I used the inspect tool to find the HTML associated to the 'salary' box. it was stored within HTML tag: <div class="metadata salary-snippet-container"><div aria-label="$40,000 to $60,000 a year" class="salary-snippet"><span>$40,000 - $60,000 a year</span></div></div>

Answer (score 0):

These containers have not mentioned salary but some are exists, therefore if you find from root `s = soup.find` is incorrect. In this case you just have to specify salary_item then check whether it is None, if not None, write down the text.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://au.indeed.com/jobs?q=Software%20Engineer&l=Adelaide%20Region%20SA&radius=100&vjk=ca36e39d39db9210"
r = requests.get(url)

webpage = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")


job_card = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'job_seen_beacon'})
for item in job_card:
    job_title = item.find('h2', {'class': 'jobTitle'}).text.strip()

    company = item.find('span', {'class': 'companyName'}).text.strip()

    salary_item = item.find('div', {'class':'metadata salary-snippet-container'})
    salary = salary_item.text.strip() if salary_item is not None else ''
    print(job_title, company, salary, sep=';')
```

Results:

```
Software Engineer;BOEING;
Software Engineer;WiseTech Global;
Software Engineer (Integrations);Honeywell;
Software Support Engineer;Fivecast;
Software Engineer (Practitioner);Rheinmetall Defence Australia Pty Ltd;
Software Engineer;Fivecast;
Software Engineer (PC Applications);Codan Limited;
newSoftware Engineer;Paxus Australia Pty Ltd;
Full Stack Software Engineer;Honeywell;
Software Engineer Staff - ATMS;Lockheed Martin Australia;
Software Test Engineer;Topcon Positioning Systems;
newSoftware Engineer - Data and Analytics;Capgemini Australia;
Software Engineer;QinetiQ;
Lead Software Engineer;The University of Adelaide;$116,557 - $124,698 a year
Senior Software Engineer;WiseTech Global;
```

Comment: Thank you! do you know why only one salary is printing (second line from bottom)?

Comment: Simply it is not provided from Job Description